# The difference between Packet network and Datagram network

Tags: switching

My professor differentiates between Datagram network and Packet network. But I don't get the difference between the two. I believe that Datagram network is just a sub-term under Packet network as a connectionless-oriented which differentiates it from a virtual-circuit network(also a sub-term under packet network). As part of an exercise, I was asked under which condition is the performance of a Datagram network the same as a Packet network. I don't know how to even begin answering this question. Could someone please explain the difference to me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic according to the Help Center. "We do not accept education questions of any kind, be they certification questions or degree questions. The answers to these questions are likely to change quickly and are most likely to solicit debate and opinion (rather than clear, concrete answers.)

However, edu/cert questions are welcome in the Network Engineering Recommendations Chat Room."  Please see which type of questions are allowed, and which type are not.